# Can't resolve symbol 'setText' error

Tags: android, textview, settext

like the title says I'm getting an error when trying to set a text view text from java in my android project, I can't see why.

```
    package com.codeherenow.sicalculator;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;

    public class SICalculatorActivity extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
public double years;
public TextView YT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);
}
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int i, boolean b){
        years = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){

    }
YT.setText(years + " Year(s)");
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple issues.

First, you can't do this here

```
public TextView YT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
```

Because the layout hasn't been inflated yet so you can't look for your `View` witht `findViewById()`. You can declare it there

```
public TextView YT;
```

but you need to initialize it **after** you call `setContentVie()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);

    //can't do it before that line ^
    YT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
}
```

And you are trying to call `setText()` outside of a method. Move that to some method. But you can't do it in `onCreate()` because `Years` isn't given a value. So you probably want it somewhere else. Maybe in `onProgressChanged()`.

Also, to follow Java naming conventions, you should name your variables by starting with lower case (yt or yT and years).

Comment: Plus 1 for insisting on naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

```
public TextView YT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
```

statement must write onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

This `YT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);` and `YT.setText(years + " Year(s)");` must be moved into the `onCreate()` method

So, leave this

```
public TextView YT;
```

And initialize it here:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);

    YT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
    YT.setText(years + " Year(s)");
}
```

**[EDIT]**

If you want a dynamic change with the progress value:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int i, boolean b)
{
    //years = i;
    YT.setText(i + " Year(s)");
}
```

Comment: I just edited my answer. `setText()` can't be left floating into the declaration space.

Answer (score 0):

Example XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myAwesomeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Escriba el mensaje y luego clickee el canal a ser enviado"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

example activity class

```
//in your OnCreate() method
TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeTextView);
myAwesomeTextView.setText("My Awesome Text");
```

So you need to add

```
YT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
```

inside onCreate method